# SASS + Compass - Can't include font-face

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to include three fonts:

```
@include font-face("Kalisher", font-files("kalisher.ttf", truetype));
@include font-face("Bark", font-files("barkbloom.ttf", truetype));
@include font-face("Bilbo", font-files("narkbilbo.ttf", truetype));
```

Only Kalisher gets included (no matter in what order I place them).

Any directions?

Compiled CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Kalisher";
  src: url('/css/fonts/kalisher.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Bark";
  src: url('/css/fonts/barkbloom.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Bilbo";
  src: url('/css/fonts/narkbilbo.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Would you please explain what you mean by 'Only Kalisher gets included (no matter in what order I place them)'? The compiled CSS looks fine. Do you mean that text on your site using Bark or Bilbo doesn't actually use Bark or Bilbo?

Comment: Indeed. It uses the default font.

Answer (score 0):

The Sass and compiled CSS looks fine. Check the fonts to confirm they are in fact web-fonts or not corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

in your config.rb don't forget to put this line:

```
fonts_path = File.join(dir, 'yourPathfromYourMain.css', 'fonts')
```

ok then this is a sass font declaration:

```
@include font-face("Kalisher", font-files("kalisher.ttf", truetype));
```

ok the font generated

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Kalisher";
    src: url('/css/fonts/kalisher.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

has you can see url start by /

remove the / in the generated css file and try, you will see your font works, so my recommendation is check your config path, all your path..